# Detect when X-axis inputs and Y-axis inputs go high

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, object-detection, system-verilog

I am working on a module named `PinCoordinates` that detects when X-axis and Y-axis inputs go high. This will be programmed onto an Altera MAX V CPLD. I am constructing a laser grid array that has a total of 50 lasers. There are 25 X-axis lasers and 25 for the y-axis. On the opposite end of the array, there are photodiodes. I hope to be able to detect objects passing through the grid and return the coordinates.

For the code, pins 1-25 represent X axis lasers, and 26-50 are for the Y-axis. The code is as follows:

```
module PinCoordinates(
input wire [49:0] pins,           // 50 pins input
output reg [4:0] x_coordinate,    // Output X coordinate pins (1-25)
output reg [4:0] y_coordinate,    // Output Y coordinate pins (26-50)
output reg output_valid           // Output indicating valid coordinates
);

integer i;
reg x_detected, y_detected; // Flags to indicate detection of X and Y coordinates

always @* begin
// Reset detection flags at the beginning of each evaluation
    x_detected = 1'b0;
    y_detected = 1'b0;
    output_valid = 1'b0;

    // Check for high X coordinate
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i = i + 1) begin
        if (pins[i] == 1'b1) begin
            x_coordinate = i + 1; // X coordinate pin numbering starts from 1
            x_detected = 1'b1;    // Set X coordinate detection flag
     
        end
    end
    // Check for high Y coordinate
    for (i = 25; i < 50; i = i + 1) begin
        if (pins[i] == 1'b1) begin
            y_coordinate = i - 24; // Y coordinate pin numbering starts from 26
            y_detected = 1'b1;     // Set Y coordinate detection flag
        
        end
    end

    // Output is valid only if both X and Y coordinates are detected
    if (x_detected && y_detected) begin
        output_valid = 1'b1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

I understand that one of the upgrades that I could make to this code is to include a `break` after either an X-pin or Y-pin is discovered to be high; however, since Verilog doesn't support `break` statements, I'm not sure how to implement this. Any more ideas in what I should do to the code? Any assistance or criticism would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

You've done a good job with the following:

- Code layout and use of indentation
- Using compact ANSI-style module ports
- Using the compact implicit sensitivity list `@*`
- Using descriptive names for the module and the signals
- Using descriptive comments

### Latches

Using `always @*` implies that you intend to describe purely *combinational*
logic, but it simulates as a latch, which is a type of *sequential* logic.
This code will infer latches when it is synthesized.  You will likely get
warning messages about that when you try to synthesize it.

The reason it behaves like a latch is because some signals are not assigned
under all conditions.  Specifically, `x_coordinate` is not assigned when
`i` is in the range 25 to 49.  In this case, `x_coordinate` retains its state,
inferring a latch.

You should be able to easily observe this behavior in simulations by looking
at waveforms of the `pins` and `x_coordinate` signals.

One way to avoid the unintended latches is to initialize the signal in the
`always` block, as you did for `x_detected`.  For example:

```
always @* begin
// Reset detection flags at the beginning of each evaluation
    x_detected   = 1'b0;
    x_coordinate = 0;
```

`y_coordinate` will also infer latches.

### Simpler

In Verilog, it is customary to omit explicitly comparing a 1-bit signal to 1.
For example:

```
    if (pins[i] == 1'b1) begin
```

is more simply written as:

```
    if (pins[i]) begin
```

This is a matter of preference, not functionality.

### Partitioning

With small designs, it is common to add all code to a single `always` block
as you have done.  However, as people start adding more logic, they sometimes
fall into the trap of cramming everything into the same block.

Generally, it is easier to understand code which is split into multiple
blocks based on functionality.  For example, the X and Y logic are really
independent of each other and can easily be partitioned into separate blocks.
Here is what the X logic would look like:

```
always @* begin
    // Reset detection flags at the beginning of each evaluation
    x_detected   = 1'b0;
    x_coordinate = 0;

    // Check for high X coordinate
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i = i + 1) begin
        if (pins[i]) begin
            x_coordinate = i + 1; // X coordinate pin numbering starts from 1
            x_detected   = 1'b1;  // Set X coordinate detection flag
        end
    end
end
```

There would be another `always` block for just the Y logic.

Since the valid signal depends on both X and Y, it would be outside of
both blocks.  It can also be simplified by using a continuous assignment
instead of a procedural assignment (one inside an `always` block):

```
output output_valid           // Output indicating valid coordinates

// ...

assign output_valid = (x_detected && y_detected);
```

Note that I removed the `reg` keyword from the output port declaration.

Another simplification is to factor the `x_detected` logic out of the block as well.  You could use a "reduction-OR" operator to do a bitwise OR of pins 0 to 24.  If any of the pins is set, then it is detected; otherwise, if all pins are 0, it is not detected:

```
wire x_detected = |pins[24:0];
```

The same could be done for Y.

### SystemVerilog

SystemVerilog (SV) features were added to the language nearly 20 years ago, and
all tool chains support these features to some degree.  Annoyingly,
many tools have these features disabled by default, which means you
may need enable the features with some sort of tool settings.  Refer to
your simulation/synthesis documentation.

Using SV syntax has its advantages.

You can replace `always @*` with `always_comb`.  Not only does it
convey the design intent better, but it also provides built-in checking
if your tool has the capability to do so.

Code can be simpler to understand using the terse `int` keyword and `++`
operator in the `for` loop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) begin
```

This has the advantage of declaring the `i` variable closer to where it is
used.

The compact syntax, `'0`, can be used to set all bits of a signal to 0.

### break

> Verilog doesn't support break statements

SV does have a `break` keyword, but there is no need to use it here.

---

Here is the code with the suggestions above:

```
module PinCoordinates (
    input wire [49:0] pins,
    output reg [4:0] x_coordinate,    // Output X coordinate pins (1-25)
    output reg [4:0] y_coordinate,    // Output Y coordinate pins (26-50)
    output output_valid               // Output indicating valid coordinates
);

// Flags to indicate detection of X and Y coordinates
wire x_detected = |pins[24:0];
wire y_detected = |pins[49:25];

assign output_valid = (x_detected && y_detected);

always_comb begin
    // Reset at the beginning of each evaluation
    x_coordinate = '0;

    // Check for high X coordinate
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) begin
        if (pins[i]) begin
            x_coordinate = i + 1; // X coordinate pin numbering starts from 1
        end
    end
end

always_comb begin
    // Reset at the beginning of each evaluation
    y_coordinate = '0;

    // Check for high Y coordinate
    for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++) begin
        if (pins[i]) begin
            y_coordinate = i + 1; // Y coordinate pin numbering starts from 1
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```